# Using Hooks Breaks Gatsby / React Starter App

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-hooks, gatsby

I installed the Gatsby starter app [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world). It works fine until I add a hook (i.e. replace the index.js with the code below):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default () => {
  const [greeting, setGreeting] = useState('hi'); // Adding this line breaks it - this is the only change I make
  return (
    <div>Whatever</div>
  );
}
```

The error is:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I verified that none of the [common solutions](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) apply.

Some info about my system:

```
node -v // v12.14.1
npm -v // 6.13.4

npm list -g --depth=0                                                               
`-- gatsby-cli@2.8.23

npm list react
+-- gatsby@2.18.12
| `-- gatsby-cli@2.8.19
|   `-- react@16.12.0  deduped
`-- react@16.12.0

npm list --depth=0                                                                  gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0 C:\code\my-hello-world-starter
+-- gatsby@2.18.12
+-- prettier@1.19.1
+-- react@16.12.0
`-- react-dom@16.12.0

npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta, required by tsutils@3.17.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta, required by tsutils@3.17.1
```

Please help - I am at a loss. I saw another article about windows path case-sensitivity, but it appears to not apply to powershell and was supposed to be fixed in these versions.

I have tried:

```
rm -r node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm cache clean -f
npm i
```

I have also deleted all global npm packages other than gatsby.

Comment: Can you add the code where you are using this component?

Comment: It's the index page, it loads first. My code is EXACTLY like here, except the one change I posted: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world/blob/master/src/pages/index.js

Comment: I cloned your project and replaced the index js with the above code and it's working fine for me

Comment: @AtinSingh Yea, it's working fine for the co-worker next to me too, that's the problem - it's not working for me. What are your node/npm versions?

Comment: this is a good question

Answer (score 2):

This was a red herring. What really broke the app was running `gatsby develop` from:

`c/code/myapp` rather than `c:/Code/myapp`. Note that `Code` is capitalized in the "correct" example. Github issues said this was fixed a few versions ago, but it's not. Hopefully this helps someone else.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3609